# How do I configure a mikrotik router to run on IPv6?

Tags: router, ipv6, mikrotik

I am experimenting with ipv6 and would like to connect to my Mikrotik router via ipv6 on a local level.  This would include connecting to it by an ip6 address, and interacting via icmp6.  I have installed the ipv6 package and made sure it was enabled through the command line.

Since it seems many people on here only like to be insulting instead of answering a simple question, please be assured I have actually spent quite a bit of time trying to find the answer to this question.  How can I connect to the router and interact with it ONLY by ipv6? (no IP4)

Comment: Please show us what you have already done, the relevant parts of the configuration and where you get stuck. The StackExchange websites are not suited for giving complete how-to instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!  I connected to the router by using winbox and the default ipv4 address.  I can also connect to it by typing that ipv4 address into a browser window.

From within winbox, I typed "system package print" to reveal all packages available for the router.  I saw that ipv6 was on the list, but was disabled, so I typed "system package enable ipv6" to enable the package, then rebooted the router.  Ipv6 is now enabled, and I typed "ipv6 address print" to find a list of available ipv6 addresses.

I opened a browser window, and pasted the IPv6 address I got from my list. NOTE: IPv6 addresses cannot be used in quite the same was as IP4.  They must be surrounded in square brackets, like so: [xx:xxx::xx etc].  That worked!  I am now connected by IPv6.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to manage your mikrotik over IPv6, and you restrict the services you can administer it over to a specific IP range in IP > services, you have to specify an IPv6 range also if you want it reachable over IPv6. Also note that winbox can handle link local addresses like [fe80::0c:baff:fe38:3823%eth0], which is very handy if (when?) you accidentally disable an address you are managing the router with.